# How do I give 5000+ symbols streaming data request from CSV file in Python?

Tags: python, excel, csv, streaming, algorithmic-trading

I am trying to create a Stock Screener. I have live streaming data from my broker. It's code is as follows:

```
value=[{"symbol":"3880_NSE"},{"symbol":"338_NSE"},{"symbol":"1270_NSE"},{"symbol":"10604_NSE"},{"symbol":"11195_NSE"}]
samco.set_streaming_data(value)
samco.start_streaming()
```

But how should I give 5000 symbols from the CSV/Excel file in one go in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
example_with_list = []
with open("EXCELFILE.csv") as data:
        csv_reader_objekt = csv.reader(data)
        for row in csv_reader_objekt:
            example_with_list.append(row)
```

Create a list with all Rows from the csv file.

Comment: Is it solved or is something unclear? If not, pls edit or comment!